# Compare hdfs file with unix file, getting error

Tags: bash

I'm getting `syntax error near unexpected token (` for this code. It runs fine until I put the `diff` line in it:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.csv
  hdfs dfs -test -e $target_dir/$f
  if [ $? = 0 ]
  then
    echo File exists. check if its same hadoop v unix
    if diff <(hdfs dfs -cat $target_dir/$f) <(cat $f)
    then
      echo Files are the same
    fi
  fi
done
```

Any ideas please? Thanks

Comment: [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) may help you with issues like this

Comment: Side note: using someting like an md5 hash of both files will be much faster than `diff`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in *.csv; do
  hdfs dfs -test -e "$target_dir/$f"
  rc=$?
  if [[ "$rc" == 0 ]]; then
    echo "File exists. check if its same hadoop v unix"
    if diff <(hdfs dfs -cat "$target_dir/$f") <(cat "$f") ; then
      echo "Files are the same"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Your do/while, if then syntax is wrong.

Comment: You can verify the syntax of the bash script by doing `bash -n <script_file>`

Comment: Thanks Vivek. Yes, I was using fi and done of course. I copied the code you posted above but same error is happening. Shellcheck thinks everything is ok.

Comment: @Angus Are you sure your shell is "bash"?

Comment: Yes, its bash, the shebang is at the top. OK, so when I run it using `$  test.sh` I get the error `syntax error near unexpected token (` but when I run it using `$ ./test.sh` it works fine. Why might this be please?  Thanks!

Comment: Do `echo "$PATH"`. When do you test.sh and if it is working, then bash is pulling the tesh.sh from one of the locations of your "$PATH" variable. My guess is that there is one more file "test.sh" in your $PATH

Comment: I think the code is bash-specific? Won't work under sh. Something to do with posix compatibility??